# Can I use Cleave even if there's only one enemy?

Tags: dnd-4e, fighter, attack

The target for `Cleave` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=992)] says "One creature", but the effect states that another enemy adjacent to you that isn't the target takes damage.

Does this mean I can use `Cleave` even if there aren't two creatures near me?

Comment: How would that differ from a basic melee attack, then?

Comment: There are a number of feats that make this quite quite useful. Deft Hurler off the top of my head.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**

You can, but with no valid secondary target, the extra damage would be wasted.

Comment: Agreed.  Likely he is aiming to use one of the secondary effects.  I know my fighter will always use Cleave due to the bonus he gets from Longhand Student